# Configure Axios to provide a more detailed error when it fails a request from a react component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I have this Axios call in my React component to save a 'team' object to an API which then saves to the database.

```
const updateTeam = async (team) => {
    await axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "api/teams/" + team.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(team),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
};
```

And I call it like this:

```
updateTeam(updatedTeam);
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
PUT https://localhost:44376/api/teams/50 400

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

And that's all I get.

I even put a breakpoint in my API backend, but it is never hit at all.

Is there a way to get a more detailed error from Axios?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this might help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967779/axios-handling-errors

Comment: please upload server endpoint `/api/teams/:id` code