# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): error.response is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When submitting form I get the following following error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): error.response is undefined

handleLogin/<
D:/project3.0/containerapp/src/login.js:74

71 |     props.history.push('/dashboard');

72 |   }).catch(error => {

73 |     setLoading(false);

> 74 |     if (error.response.status === 401) setError(error.response.data.message);

|^75 |     else setError("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
76 |   });
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { setUserSession } from './Utils/Common';

function Login(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const username = useFormInput('');
  const password = useFormInput('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
 
  // handle button click of login form
  const handleLogin = () => {
    setError(null);
    setLoading(true);
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/signin', { username: username.value, password: password.value }).then(response => {
      setLoading(false);
      setUserSession(response.data.token, response.data.user);
      props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }).catch(error => {
      setLoading(false);
      if (error.response.status === 401) setError(error.response.data.message);
      else setError("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
    });
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
      Login<br /><br />
      <div>
        Username<br />
        <input type="text" {...username} autoComplete="new-password" />
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        Password<br />
        <input type="password" {...password} autoComplete="new-password" />
      </div>
      {error && <><small style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</small><br /></>}<br />
      <input type="button" value={loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Login'} onClick={handleLogin} disabled={loading} /><br />
    </div>
  );
}
 
const useFormInput = initialValue => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
 
  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }
  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange
  }
}
 
export default Login;
```

Comment: Looks like your backend isn't sending the response you are expecting when an error is fired.

Can you `console.log('error object: ', {error})` inside of your catch block to see what you get as an error response?

Comment: yeah localhost:4000 is not woking and i am not sure how to start it.why it is going in catch block.why it is not saving data of login

Comment: Once you get a response other than in the 200 status code range, axios will handle it as an error, so you can rely on the catch block to provide a good error message without having to check the status code of the response.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously - the `error` object doesn't contain the `response` field. In the context of using `axios` - that basically means that the request is not performed properly (and there's no response from the server at all)

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51768316/8252978) answer:

A conventional approach is to catch errors in the `catch()` block like below:

```
axios.get('/api/xyz/abcd')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // Request made and server responded
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }

  });
```