# Axios response undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a little problem while displaying server auth response after axios post req. I'm trying to console log server response errorMessage: "please all required fields after form submit. Console keeps showing "undefined". On the server side everything is fine, the network tab shows correct response.

```
const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState("");

  const { getLoggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const history = useHistory();
  async function login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const loginData = {
        email,
        password,
      };

      const res = await axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", loginData)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.data);
        });

      await getLoggedIn();

      history.push("/player");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.data);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="authWrapper">
      <form className="box" onSubmit={login}>
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <input
          autoComplete="off"
          className="input"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          value={email}
        />
        <input
          autoComplete="off"
          className="input"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          value={password}
        />
        <button className="submit" type="submit">
          {`Log in${" "}`}
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight}></FontAwesomeIcon>
        </button>

        <Link to="/register">
          <button className="changeForm">
            {`Register${" "}`}
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSync}></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </button>
        </Link>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
<div></div>;
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuELv.png)

[Network login endpoint response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8qVc.png)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967779/axios-handling-errors/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are both waiting for the response using `async/await` and use a promise chaining line `.post().then().catch()`

Try this:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", loginData)
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.data);
          await getLoggedIn();
          history.push("/player");
        })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err)
      })
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add something to what has been already said. You don't need to use **.then()** for promises if you are using **await**.
You can try it this way:

```
const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", loginData)
console.log(res.data);
```

You'll be waiting for a response from the server. Once you get it, it will be stored in the res constant that you created.
Also, you need to add a **catch** block after every **try** you write.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a promise, an exception is not going to be thrown, so it will not hit your try catch block.  You need to add the catch on the promise instead:

```
      const res = await axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", loginData)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch