# How to use a conditional validation after Axios call in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I have a Vue application where I make a `POST` request to my backend. I am now trying to call a validation method after the response from my backend returned back an error to my frontend. But for some reason my code is not executed:

UPDATED QUESTION CODE:

```
     validateFormInput(){
      this.$refs.form.validate()
    },
  saveSelectionVoter() {
    var pageURL = window.location.href;
    var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.votersSelectArray.voterAvailableTimes = [...this.votersSelectArray.voterAvailableTimes, ...this.selected]

    console.log(JSON.stringify( this.votersSelectArray))

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/votercontroller/",
        this.votersSelectArray,
        {
          params: {
            meetingName: lastURLSegment,
          }
        },
    ).then(function(response){
    })

        .catch(function (error){
          this.validateFormInput()
    console.log(error)
    })
    this.selected = []


  },
```

This causes a new error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateFormInput' of undefined
```

Comment: response errors (> 400 status code)  will be in the `catch` block because it failed from the server side (422 is validation error).

Comment: But my response.data is send to my frontend? I can see it inside the console under networks -> preview can I not use it somehow? Or what would be your suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios handling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967779/axios-handling-errors)

Comment: I updated my code to catch the error which is catched, but if I try to validate now my code I am getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateFormInput' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

always have a catch to see the error return
axios return you a promise so it captures the error if there is any

```
axios.post('url')
  .then((res) => {
   // do somthing 
  }).catch(err){
   console.log(err)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the callback method to catch the response/error or use the Promise way, which is my favorite because of scope and readability.

You start by declaring your function with async

```
async saveSelectionVoter() {
```

Then you use a try/catch block to handle the response/error:

```
try{
const response = await axios.post(url, params)
 // handle response here
} catch (error) {
// handle error here
}
```

Comment: I updated my code thanks for the answer but I had seen it too late, maybe you can take a look at my new problem with the updated question