# Storing strings in react component state

Tags: reactjs

I have a Register component that sends a POST request to the API and if the registration is successful just show the user a notification and redirect to login page (for now). If not, the server sends back status 400 and a message. When I receive the response, I set a state variable `serverError` to true and `serverMessage` to whatever I received from the server to show it to the user.

POST Request logic:

```
export const registerRequest = (state, setState) => {
  axios.post("api/auth/register", {
   "email": state.email, "password": state.password, "firstName": state.firstName, "lastName": state.lastName
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            setState({
                ...state,
                serverError: false
            });
        }
    }).catch((exception) => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            serverMessage: exception.response.data,
            serverError: true,
        });
    });
}
```

First I tried doing this "show user what's wrong" in the function dealing with form submit but I kept getting `serverError === true` but `serverMessage` being equal to an empty string (as declared in state). So next I tried using a `componentDidUpdate` equivalent in `useEffect` with the required dependencies and `didMount` `useRef` hook to make sure I show the notification only after the component is updated (i.e. after state update). Didn't work either.

`useEffect` and `handleSubmit` hook/function (`useHistory` is from `react-router-dom` and `Notification` is an antD component that takes a title and a description):

```
const { serverError, serverMessage } = state;
const didMountRef = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (didMountRef.current) {
        if (serverError) {
            StyleImports.Notification["success"]({
                message: [JsonImports.registerNotificationSuccess],
                description: [JsonImports.registerSuccessDetails]
            });
            setTimeout(() => { history.push("/"); }, 4.5 * 1000);
        }
        else {
            StyleImports.Notification["error"]({
                message: [JsonImports.registerNotificationFail],
                description: serverMessage
            });
        }
    }
    else didMountRef.current = true;
    
}, [serverError, serverMessage, history]);


const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // just some form validation logic before form submission
    event.preventDefault();
    registerRequest(state, setState);
    // commented just to show you what I did initially
    /*if (state.serverError) {
        StyleImports.Notification["success"]({
            message: [JsonImports.registerNotificationSuccess],
            description: [JsonImports.registerSuccessDetails]
        });
        setTimeout(() => { history.push("/"); }, 4.5 * 1000);
    }
    else {
        StyleImports.Notification["error"]({
            message: [JsonImports.registerNotificationFail],
            description: state.serverMessage
        });
    }*/
}
```

Any ideas on how to handle this properly? Just showing some message declared in a JSON client-side is not a good idea in my opinion since I can get different messages from the server. I guess `setState` didn't actually update `serverMessage` since it's a pretty big string and would take more time?

Comment: Did you try printing the value of `exception.response.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what kind of error you have and what message you get from your backend.

First i would suggest to debug your `exception` property and have a look what data is available. Just set a breakpoint at the `setState({` line or add a `console.log(error)` before this line. Please inspect whats inside your `exception`.

After this you can handle the different error cases e.g.:

```js
...
.catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // Request made and server responded
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
```

or maybe this fits your data? It all depends to what is inside your error

```js
  .catch(error => {
     console.log(error.response.data.error)
  })
```

Please have a look the [axios-handling-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967779/axios-handling-errors)s thread too.

BTW this looks like a bug? `serverError` is maybe no success ;-)

```js
if (serverError) {
            StyleImports.Notification["success"]({
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be it. I didn't focus on that at all, I thought there was something wrong with my logic. Thanks.